# Graph chromatic number proof

Tags: graph-theory

How can i prove this?

Show proof that for any edge $e$ of graph $G$ we have $\chi(G-e)\leq\chi(G)\leq\chi(G-e)+1$. Give examples showing that the inequalities are sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $\chi(G - e) \le \chi(G)$ since $G-e$ is a subgraph.

To show the other inequality, set $e = xy$, and suppose we have a coloring of $G-e$ that uses $\chi(G-e)$ colors.  Add a color to $G$, and try to show that you can recolor the vertices of $G$ so that $x$ and $y$ do not have the same color.

> Take the vertices of $G-e$ and simply change the color of $x$ to this new color to make sure that $x$ and $y$ do not have the same color in $G$.  It is easy to show that this is a coloring for $G$, since no adjacent vertices have the same color.

To show that the inequalities are sharp, find an example of a graph where adding an edge leaves the chromatic number the same, and another graph where adding an edge increases the chromatic number by one.

> For the first, you might try the path $P_4$ and the cycle $C_4$ (both have chromatic number $2$) and for the second, you might try $P_3$ and $C_3$ (the first has chromatic number $2$, but the second has chromatic number $3$).